# The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I try to use this query -> C# linq...

```
select patn, rf, row_number() over( partition by  patn  order by
executiondate,rf )  as rf_num, name, conv,conv_type, recorddate,
executiondate  from store_temp2
```

My C# code:

> ```
>         DataTable store_temp = new DataTable();  
>         store_temp.Columns.Add("patn");
>         store_temp.Columns.Add("rf");
>         store_temp.Columns.Add("name");
>         store_temp.Columns.Add("conv");
>         store_temp.Columns.Add("conv_type");
>         store_temp.Columns.Add("recorddate");
>         store_temp.Columns.Add("executiondate");
> ```

```
        var rowsgroups = from row in store_temp.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row =>row.Field<string>("executiondate"))
                         .OrderBy((g=> g.OrderByDescending(y=>y.Field<string>("executiondate")).ThenByDescending(y=> y.Field<string>("rf"))))
                       .Select((n,i) => 
                           new {
                            patn = n.ElementAt(0).ToString(),
                            rf = n.ElementAt(1).ToString(),
                            rf_num = i+1,
                            name = n.ElementAt(2).ToString() ,
                            conv = n.ElementAt(3).ToString(),
                            conv_type = n.ElementAt(4).ToString(),
                            recorddate = n.ElementAt(5).ToString(),
                            executiondate = n.ElementAt(6).ToString() 

                       }).ToArray();
```

it has 2 errors... please help me :'(

**Error 1**

> A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

**Error 2**

> The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'

Comment: Start by removing `from row in `

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you are mixing Linq syntax and lambda syntax incorrectly. Try something like this..

```
int i=1;
var rowsgroups = (from row in store_temp.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row =>row.Field<string>("executiondate"))
                 .OrderBy((g=> g.OrderByDescending(y=>y.Field<string>("executiondate")).ThenByDescending(y=> y.Field<string>("rf"))))
                select 
                   new {
                    patn = row.ElementAt(0).ToString(),
                    rf = row.ElementAt(1).ToString(),
                    rf_num = i++,
                    name = row.ElementAt(2).ToString() ,
                    conv = row.ElementAt(3).ToString(),
                    conv_type = row.ElementAt(4).ToString(),
                    recorddate = row.ElementAt(5).ToString(),
                    executiondate = row.ElementAt(6).ToString() 

               }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3d02c96a-b3db-4e67-9b54-c08dbb5cc988/row-number-in-linq-query?forum=csharpgeneral). I think same problem on MSDN.

```
    var rowsgroups =  from row in store_temp.GroupBy(row =>row.Field<string>("executiondate"))
                      .OrderBy((g=> g.OrderByDescending(y=>y.Field<string>("executiondate")).ThenByDescending(y=> y.Field<string>("rf"))))
                      .AsEnumerable()//and please try .AsEnumerable() here
                      .Select((n,index) => 
                      new {
                            index,
                            patn = n.ElementAt(0).ToString(),
                            rf = n.ElementAt(1).ToString(),
                            rf_num = i+1,
                            name = n.ElementAt(2).ToString() ,
                            conv = n.ElementAt(3).ToString(),
                            conv_type = n.ElementAt(4).ToString(),
                            recorddate = n.ElementAt(5).ToString(),
                            executiondate = n.ElementAt(6).ToString() 

                       }).ToArray();
```